# Rails elasticsearch aggregation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

Somehow I can't seem to get a response containing my aggregations...

Using curl it works as expected:

```
HBZUMB01$ curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/contents/_search" -d '{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sport_count": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "dwid"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I get the response:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 90,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "sport_count": {
      "value": 399
    }
  }
}
```

However using the code in rails:

```
query = '{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sport_count": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "dwid"
      }
    }
  }
}'
@response = Content.search(query).to_json
```

and rendering it in the browser

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do    
  render text: "#{@response}"   
end
```

I get an empty response:

```
[  ]
```

How can I print my aggregations here which I got with curl?

Comment: What is the gem you are using to integrate Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was also struggling with this, but now I found out how to get the aggregation results.

If you're using the **elasticsearch-rails** with **elasticsearch-model** gems, when you run an aggregation on a model, you can get the buckets like in this example:

```
 agg = Model.search( 
     query: { match: { param: 'value' } }, 
     aggs: {my_aggregation_name: { terms: { field: :my_field} }} 
 )
```

In your RoR code:

```
agg.response["aggregations"]["my_aggregation_name"]["buckets"]
```

From that, you'll get a result like this:

```
[{"key"=>"banana",
  "doc_count"=>1963,
  "score"=>478.30920868573355,
  "bg_count"=>2152},
 {"key"=>"potato",
  "doc_count"=>1212,
  "score"=>315.68857496078505,
  "bg_count"=>1243}, ...]
```

Then you can do whatever you want! Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm using ElasticSearch 2.x, and the above _mostly_ worked for me, but I needed to do `agg.response.aggregations.my_aggregation_name.buckets`. The "hash format" didn't work for me. Also, if you want to just return counts, you can pass `search_type: 'count'` as a second parameter to `Model#search`.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the ES version, but rather the es-rails and es-model versions. For me, `Model.search` returns Hashie::Mash objects, so both syntaxes should work fine.