# ElasticSearch Range Aggregation no output results with no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

Hello I've got this problem with the rails Elascticsearch range aggregations, it seems right as there's no error output but then again it also doesn't aggregate.

Heres my controller

```
def results
    min_price = params[:min_price] if params[:min_price].present?
    max_price = params[:max_price] if params[:max_price].present?

    price_ranges = [{to: max_price}, {from: min_price, to: max_price}, {from: min_price}]
    @results = Item.search(params[:q], aggs: {item_final_price: {ranges: price_ranges}}, page: params[:page], per_page: 10) if params[:q].present?
end
```

and my model

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord

include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
# Item.import

searchkick callbacks: :async, highlight: [:item_name]



   def search_data
        {
            item_name: item_name,
            item_details: item_details,
            item_final_price: item_final_price,
            item_av_rating: item_av_rating
        }
    end
end
```

and my views

```
<%= form_tag results_path, method: :get, enforce_utf8: false, id: "q_filter" do %>
<section class="widget widget-categories">
    <%= hidden_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
    <h3 class="widget-title">Price Range</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Price Between</label>
        <%= number_field_tag :min_price, params[:min_price], class: "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder: "Min Price" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>And</label>
        <%= number_field_tag :max_price, params[:max_price], class: "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder: "Max Price" %>
    </div>
    <%= button_tag(type: "submit", name: nil, class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block") do %>
        Filter Search
    <% end %>
</section>
```

```
<% @results.each do |item| %>
   <%= item.item_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are your sure params are getting passed correctly? Just be cause you get no error doesn't mean the search returns any results.

Comment: yes it passes correctly here are the results
https://prnt.sc/jh6ak7

Comment: But does the curl return any results?

Comment: Yes I has  same with the view theres result but as you can see not with the data that i want 

see the 2 picture 
https://prnt.sc/jhbf9w
https://prnt.sc/jhbgfc

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981332/rails-elasticsearch-aggregation#26221981

Answer (score 0):

Try to target this in your view

```
@results.response["aggregations"]["item_final_price"]["buckets"]
```

If you're running in development, can you throw a `binding.pry` and see what the result keys are?  The data should be there if the query returns results.

Comment: theres an error `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

http://prntscr.com/jhcct6